# Handling 512 bit numbers

Tags: vb.net, hash, cryptography, numbers, sha

I need to convert SHA-512 hex strings to integers and perform arithmetic functions with out my program crashing. I have only found ways to handle up to 64 bit numbers so far. How can I handle larger numbers?

Comment: You could look at the [BigInteger Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It can hold integers of any length.

Comment: Hello sorry to be a bit awkward...i did have a look at the link,it looks good and that but it looks confusing on how i would implement it.For example if i wrote a value into a text box how would i make a big integer object from that?

Comment: Actuly forget what i just asked,was looking at it wrong.Thankyou, i will test it now and will let you know how it works

Comment: right,i have a problem vb.net is not reconising the big integer funtion,i cannot sign a value in the big integer format.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. You do need to add a reference to `System.Numerics`. How you do that may depend on which version of Visual Studio you are using. The most common way is to double-click on "My Project" in Solution Explorer, and then choose the "References" tab and use the "Add button to add the reference. Then, if you add `Imports System.Numerics` at the top of your code file, you can code `Dim bigNum As BigInteger` instead of `Dim bigNum As System.Numerics.Biginteger`

Comment: @ChristianShelton Please show us what you tried - *by adding code to the question* - and include an explanation about what you mean by "sign a value".

Comment: Hello there  i did the import through the references and everything works great. Thankyou very much my program runs better than ever before!!!